# One click deploy of multiple artifacts in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a solution with about 20 projects, each it's own service and we are moving to Azure. Currently we are using Octopus to deploy our solution and we could continue using that in Azure but if possible would like to drop it.

We don't run Continious Deployment.

What I am looking for is a way to deploy all our 20 or so projects without having to deploy them individualy. In other words I'm looking for a "button" that allows me to deploy all services to a certain environment.

I can't seem to find that does it exist?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say where you're deploying your apps to but I'm going to assume it's Azure App Service (since you said "moving to Azure"). Yes, multiple projects can be deployed using a single pipeline.

The now "legacy" way of doing this would be simply setup your build pipeline, and then setup a release pipeline with multiple stages. Each stage of your release pipeline can be one app/project.

The "modern" way that Microsoft recommends is to use the new multi-stage pipeline where you can define your build and release parameters in the same YAML template.

Here's a guide I found that shows a simple example of deploying multiple projects from a single solution to Azure App Service in Azure DevOps (this is the legacy way).
https://www.johansmarius.com/2019/10/deploying-multiple-projects-from-one_18.html

Cheers!

Comment: Thankyou, that was exactly what I was looking for.